# Spring defaults to my home.jsp rather than going to my login.jsp for authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When I launch my webapp I want spring to redirect to my login.jsp in order to authenticate before it goes to my home.jsp but when the app starts it immediately goes to my home.jsp. I created this SecurityFilterChain which I had thought would default to my login.jsp for authentication.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: If you add a matcher for /home, and then rather than .permitAll() instead use .authenticate(), I believe it will do what you want.  Ie., you are restricting access to the /home path to only authenticated users, which will spur spring into sending you to the login form URL if you are not authenticated.  This is a guess, as I am much more familiar with XML spring security config rather than java config.

Comment: `but when the app starts it immediately goes to my home.jsp` your APP goes to it? is your app automatic? I seriously doubt your app does something, you are doing a request first to what? and then what happens?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I use an external version of tomcat with the application context set to "/" so when the app deploys it goes to localhost:8080/ which would open my home page rather than looking for my login authentication page. I have solved this issue with my answer posted down below. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
As pointed out by jzheaux down below. The naming convention of the method doesn’t matter. The fix was adding the .anyRequest().authenticated() which makes sure any other page besides the ones I had specified above it require authentication before you’re able to go to them.

I found what was wrong. I was using filterChain rather than the securityFilterChain. I also modified the method a little bit as shown here

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .antMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/submit-login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Once making these changes the app defaulted to opening up my login.jsp for authentication before continuing on. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: To clarify, changing the bean name should not make a difference. You can see this in [Spring Security's samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples), where the bean name is different in several of the samples. The fix you needed is where you added `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to ensure that `/home` requires authentication.